# UIScrollView subclass, when scrolling subviews visible outside of the view

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, subclass

I subclassed the UIScroll view and i am adding it subviews programmatically and adjust the content Size. I noticed that when my scroll view is not cover the entire screen, it subviews are visible outside of it when scrolling.

what can cause it ?

Comment: Set `clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: that did it, thanks.